# Running setup.py install for pyxb ... error

Tags: python, pip, pyxb

I'm running the command `python3.9 -m pip install pyxb` in a virtual environment and receiving these errors. I cannot figure out a meaningful message inside the logs. Am I missing something?

```
(saleor-venv) ec2-user@ip-12-3-3-2:~/repo/fork/saleor> python3.9 -m pip install pyxb
Collecting pyxb
  Downloading PyXB-1.2.6.tar.gz (7.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 7.0 MB 4.5 MB/s 
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyxb, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyxb
    Running setup.py install for pyxb ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -9:
     command: /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ofpqfy5f/pyxb_5f99ab2ae6bd48aeb20205fc5a95659a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ofpqfy5f/pyxb_5f99ab2ae6bd48aeb20205fc5a95659a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vkevgofl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/include/site/python3.9/pyxb                                                                                                  
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ofpqfy5f/pyxb_5f99ab2ae6bd48aeb20205fc5a95659a/                              
    Complete output (357 lines):                                                                            
    Found bundle in /tmp/pip-install-ofpqfy5f/pyxb_5f99ab2ae6bd48aeb20205fc5a95659a/pyxb/bundles/dc         
    Found bundle in /tmp/pip-install-ofpqfy5f/pyxb_5f99ab2ae6bd48aeb20205fc5a95659a/pyxb/bundles/common     
    Found bundle in /tmp/pip-install-ofpqfy5f/pyxb_5f99ab2ae6bd48aeb20205fc5a95659a/pyxb/bundles/wssplat    
    Found bundle in /tmp/pip-install-ofpqfy5f/pyxb_5f99ab2ae6bd48aeb20205fc5a95659a/pyxb/bundles/saml20     
    running install                                                                                         
    running build                                                                                           
    running build_py                                                                                        
    creating build                                                                                          
    creating build/lib                                                                                      
    creating build/lib/pyxb                                                                                 
    copying pyxb/exceptions_.py -> build/lib/pyxb                                                           
    copying pyxb/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb                                                              
    creating build/lib/pyxb/namespace                                                                       
    copying pyxb/namespace/utility.py -> build/lib/pyxb/namespace                                           
    copying pyxb/namespace/archive.py -> build/lib/pyxb/namespace                                           
    copying pyxb/namespace/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/namespace                                          
    copying pyxb/namespace/resolution.py -> build/lib/pyxb/namespace                                        
    copying pyxb/namespace/builtin.py -> build/lib/pyxb/namespace                                           
    creating build/lib/pyxb/binding                                                                         
    copying pyxb/binding/xml_.py -> build/lib/pyxb/binding                                                  
    copying pyxb/binding/basis.py -> build/lib/pyxb/binding                                                 
    copying pyxb/binding/saxer.py -> build/lib/pyxb/binding                                                 
    copying pyxb/binding/content.py -> build/lib/pyxb/binding                                               
    copying pyxb/binding/facets.py -> build/lib/pyxb/binding                                                
    copying pyxb/binding/datatypes.py -> build/lib/pyxb/binding                                             
    copying pyxb/binding/generate.py -> build/lib/pyxb/binding                                              
    copying pyxb/binding/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/binding                                              
    creating build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                                           
    copying pyxb/utils/saxutils.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                  
    copying pyxb/utils/unicode.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                   
    copying pyxb/utils/domutils.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                  
    copying pyxb/utils/unicode_data.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                              
    copying pyxb/utils/utility.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                   
    copying pyxb/utils/activestate.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                               
    copying pyxb/utils/six.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                       
    copying pyxb/utils/templates.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                 
    copying pyxb/utils/xmlre.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                     
    copying pyxb/utils/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                  
    copying pyxb/utils/fac.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                       
    copying pyxb/utils/saxdom.py -> build/lib/pyxb/utils                                                    
    creating build/lib/pyxb/xmlschema                                                                       
    copying pyxb/xmlschema/structures.py -> build/lib/pyxb/xmlschema                                        
    copying pyxb/xmlschema/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/xmlschema                                          
    creating build/lib/pyxb/bundles                                                                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles                                              
    creating build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc                                                                      
    copying pyxb/bundles/dc/dcterms.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc                                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/dc/dcmitype.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc                                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/dc/dc.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc                                              
    copying pyxb/bundles/dc/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc                                        
    creating build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc/raw                                                                  
    copying pyxb/bundles/dc/raw/dcterms.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc/raw                                 
    copying pyxb/bundles/dc/raw/dcmitype.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc/raw                                
    copying pyxb/bundles/dc/raw/dc.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc/raw                                      
    copying pyxb/bundles/dc/raw/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc/raw                                
    creating build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common                                                                  
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/xsd_hfp.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common                                 
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/xhtml1.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common                                  
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/xlink.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common                                   
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common                                
    creating build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common/raw                                                              
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/raw/xsd_hfp.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/raw/xhtml1.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/raw/xlink.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common/raw                           
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/raw/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common/raw                        
    creating build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                                                 
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/httpbind.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                              
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsp.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                   
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsdlx.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                 
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/ds.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                    
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/xenc.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                  
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/whttp.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                 
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsrf_bf.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                               
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/mimebind.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                              
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsdli.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                 
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsp200607.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                             
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/soapbind12.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                            
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsa.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                   
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsse.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                  
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsrf_br.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                               
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/soap11.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/soapenc.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                               
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wscoor.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsrm.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                  
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                              
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/bpws.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                  
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsdl20.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/sawsdl.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsoap.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                 
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wstop.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                 
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsu.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                   
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsam.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                  
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsdl11.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/soapbind11.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                            
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/soap12.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/wsnt.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat                                  
    creating build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                                                             
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/httpbind.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                      
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsp.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                           
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsdlx.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/ds.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                            
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/xenc.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/whttp.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsrf_bf.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/mimebind.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                      
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsdli.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsp200607.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                     
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/soapbind12.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                    
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsa.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                           
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsse.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsrf_br.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/soap11.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/soapenc.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wscoor.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsrm.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                      
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/bpws.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsdl20.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/sawsdl.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsoap.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wstop.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsu.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                           
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsam.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsdl11.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/soapbind11.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                    
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/soap12.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsnt.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                          
    creating build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20                                                                  
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/xacml.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20                                   
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/assertion.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20                               
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/x500.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20                                    
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/protocol.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20                                
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/ecp.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20                                     
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20                                
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/metadata.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20                                
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/dce.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20                                     
    creating build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                                                              
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/xacml.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                           
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/assertion.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/x500.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                            
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/protocol.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/ecp.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                             
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/__init__.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/metadata.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/dce.py -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                             
    copying pyxb/bundles/dc/raw/dc.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/dc/raw                                     
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/raw/xhtml1.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/raw/xsd_hfp.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/common/raw/xlink.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/common/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/httpbind.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                     
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/ds.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                           
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsdli.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/soap12.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsoap.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsrf_bf.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                      
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/soapbind12.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                   
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsnt.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wscoor.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsrm.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsse.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/soapenc.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                      
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsdl11.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsu.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/whttp.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsp.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsa.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsdl20.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/xenc.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsdlx.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/sawsdl.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/soapbind11.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                   
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/soap11.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/bpws.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/mimebind.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                     
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wstop.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                        
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsrf_br.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                      
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsp200607.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                    
    copying pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw/wsam.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/wssplat/raw                         
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/xacml.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                          
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/protocol.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/x500.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                           
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/metadata.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                       
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/dce.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                            
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/ecp.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                            
    copying pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/assertion.wxs -> build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                      
    running build_scripts                                                                                   
    creating build/scripts-3.9                                                                              
    copying and adjusting scripts/pyxbgen -> build/scripts-3.9                                              
    copying and adjusting scripts/pyxbwsdl -> build/scripts-3.9                                             
    copying and adjusting scripts/pyxbdump -> build/scripts-3.9                                             
    changing mode of build/scripts-3.9/pyxbgen from 644 to 755                                              
    changing mode of build/scripts-3.9/pyxbwsdl from 644 to 755                                             
    changing mode of build/scripts-3.9/pyxbdump from 644 to 755                                             
    running install_lib                                                                                     
    copying build/lib/pyxb/exceptions_.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb                                                                                               
    copying build/lib/pyxb/__init__.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb                                                                                                  
    copying build/lib/pyxb/namespace/utility.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/namespace                                                                               
    copying build/lib/pyxb/namespace/archive.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/namespace                                                                               
    copying build/lib/pyxb/namespace/__init__.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/namespace                                                                              
    copying build/lib/pyxb/namespace/resolution.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/namespace                                                                            
    copying build/lib/pyxb/namespace/builtin.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/namespace                                                                               
    copying build/lib/pyxb/binding/xml_.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/binding                                                                                      
    copying build/lib/pyxb/binding/basis.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/binding                                                                                     

...

    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/dce.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20                                                                         
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/xacml.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                                                               
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/assertion.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                                                           
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/x500.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                                                                
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/protocol.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                                                            
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/ecp.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                                                                 
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/__init__.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                                                            
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/metadata.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                                                            
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/dce.py -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw                                                                 
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/xacml.wxs -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/protocol.wxs -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/x500.wxs -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/metadata.wxs -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/dce.wxs -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/ecp.wxs -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw
    copying build/lib/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw/assertion.wxs -> /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/saml20/raw
    byte-compiling /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyxb/bundles/common/raw/xhtml1.py to xhtml1.cpython-39.pyc
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -9: /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ofpqfy5f/pyxb_5f99ab2ae6bd48aeb20205fc5a95659a/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ofpqfy5f/pyxb_5f99ab2ae6bd48aeb20205fc5a95659a/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-vkevgofl/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ec2-user/repo/fork/saleor/saleor-venv/include/site/python3.9/pyxb Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error got resolved by running:

```
(saleor-venv) ec2-user@ip-12-3-3-2:~/repo/fork/saleor> python3.9 -m pip install wheel
```